# Airflow picking up queued task very slow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an airflow in the docker on AWS t2-medium, tasks are getting queued, but it seems it sometimes waits quite a while before being picked up.

It can be as long as a few minutes, and could also get stuck (not being picked up after hours).

I have the following in my config:

```
job_heartbeat_sec = 5
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "quite a while"?

Comment: @roganjosh it's pretty much uncertain, can be as long as a few minutes, and could stuck (not being picked up after hours).. I will update my post.

Comment: what's the load on the worker host when things are slow?

Comment: @gcbenison only ONE DAG with 8-10 tasks, and I think it was faster when I first created the airflow instance.

Comment: has anyone figured this out?